# How to add a Jabber contact to gtalk?

Tags: google-talk, jabber

HI there,

I thought it is trival, but I could not get it to work even with loads of googling.

So, how do I add an jabber contact to my gtalk contact list? I tried in psi, pidgon and gmail, but the jabber account does not recieve my request for authorization.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You simply add the other user's address (*user@domain*).

If they don't receive an authorization request, it might be a problem at their side.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I actually tried with accounts from two different jabber servers. Does it make a difference, that it is a google apps account?

Comment: @FrowningBeetle: I haven't used Apps' Jabber service myself, so can't say... but Apps services do work slightly differently at times.

Answer (score 1):

On a Google Apps account, you have to add a few DNS records to enable chat federation. if you login to your Apps admin account and visit the Chat settings, you'll see a link to:

http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=34143

Login to your domain management console (GoDaddy or whoever) and add the DNS records as listed in the Google support article.

This hosting company provides a useful test site here for troubleshooting:
http://www.olark.com/gtalk/check_srv

I had the same issue and after updating my DNS records, the test passed, and I was able to chat with federated (non-Google) users on talk.google.com.